# PDO - Dynamic Query building | SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, pdo

I tried to build a dynamic query, but I faced an error telling me that the parameter count is inappropriate everything seems to be ok for me there are 4 params.

### **My attempt**

```
$activeFilters 
array(1) {
      ["zlec_addres"]=>
      string(2) "Sz"
      ["zlec_nr"]=>
      string(3) "OPC"
}
function cond_gen(array $activeFilters)
{
    $query_var = [];        
    $i=0;
    foreach ($activeFilters as $key => $value) {
        $query_var[] = '`'.array_keys($activeFilters)[$i].'` LIKE concat("%",:condition'.$i.',"%")';
        $i++;
    }

    return 'WHERE ' . implode('AND', $query_var);
}

$conditions = cond_gen($activeFilters);

//eqb
$db->bindMore($activeFilters);
$db->bind("start",$start);
$db->bind("pagesize",$pagesize);
$dynQuery = $db->query("SELECT zlec_status.nazwa                       AS Status, 
       piorytet.nazwa                          AS Priorytet, 
       Concat(koord.imie, ' ', koord.nazwisko) AS `Koordynator`, 
       Concat(zlec_adresy.miasto, ' - ', zlec_adresy.ulica, ' ', 
       zlec_adresy.oddzial) 
                                               AS `adres`, 
       zlec_z_dnia,zlec_id,
       zlec_nr, 
       zlec_do, 
       zlec_ogran, 
       awizacje, 
       awizacja_na_dzien, 
       termin_zamkniecia, 
       tresc, 
       uwagi 
FROM   zlec 
       INNER JOIN koord 
               ON zlec.koord = koord.id 
       INNER JOIN zlec_adresy 
               ON zlec.zlec_addres = zlec_adresy.id 
       INNER JOIN piorytet 
               ON zlec.priorytet = piorytet.id 
       INNER JOIN zlec_status 
               ON zlec.status_zlecenia = zlec_status.id 
$conditions 
LIMIT :start, :pagesize");
```

---

SQL Error Unhandled Exception. 
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

```
WHERE `zlec_addres` LIKE concat("%",:condition0,"%")AND`zlec_nr` LIKE concat("%",:condition1,"%") 
LIMIT :start, :pagesize
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Make a foreach loop and build a query string?

Comment: Show what - how to create a string `A and B and C and D`?

Comment: So - does your attempt work? or not? or what?

Comment: Ok check the new question

Answer (score 0):

Working code for me

```
  function cond_gen(array $activeFilters)
    {
        $query_var = [];        
        $i=0;
        foreach ($activeFilters as $key => $value) {
            $query_var[] = '`'.array_keys($activeFilters)[$i].'` LIKE concat(\'%\',:'.array_keys($activeFilters)[$i].',\'%\')';
            $i++;
        }

        return 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $query_var);
    }



    $conditions = cond_gen($activeFilters);
    echo cond_gen($activeFilters);

    //eqb
    var_dump($activeFilters);
    $db->bindMore($activeFilters);
    $db->bind("start",$start);
    $db->bind("pagesize",$pagesize);
    $dynQuery = $db->query("SELECT zlec_status.nazwa                       AS Status, 
           piorytet.nazwa                          AS Priorytet, 
           Concat(koord.imie, ' ', koord.nazwisko) AS `Koordynator`, 
           Concat(zlec_adresy.miasto, ' - ', zlec_adresy.ulica, ' ', 
           zlec_adresy.oddzial) 
                                                   AS `adres`, 
           zlec_z_dnia,zlec_id,
           zlec_nr, 
           zlec_do, 
           zlec_ogran, 
           awizacje, 
           awizacja_na_dzien, 
           termin_zamkniecia, 
           tresc, 
           uwagi 
    FROM   zlec 
           INNER JOIN koord 
                   ON zlec.koord = koord.id 
           INNER JOIN zlec_adresy 
                   ON zlec.zlec_addres = zlec_adresy.id 
           INNER JOIN piorytet 
                   ON zlec.priorytet = piorytet.id 
           INNER JOIN zlec_status 
                   ON zlec.status_zlecenia = zlec_status.id 
    $conditions 
    LIMIT :start, :pagesize");
```